# Mysql - multiple Order By options in CASE WHEN

Tags: mysql

I'm pulling results from a table in SQL to generate a 'next' button link in our appointment ordering system.
The SELECT statement works, but I want to do something like this with the order by to account for situations where two appointments take place at the exact same time and date:

```
ORDER BY
     CASE Order.date
          WHEN currentDate THEN (Order.id ASC, Order.Date ASC)
          ELSE (Order.Date ASC, Order.id ASC)
          END
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write it as

```
ORDER BY
     CASE WHEN Order.date = current_date() THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ASC,
     Order.Date ASC, 
     Order.id ASC
```

It will first sort rows where Order.date is today then it will sort by date in ascending order and for same dates it will sort rows by id in ascending order